# The infamous "a test was not wrapped in act(...)"

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a test that generates the warning `An update to DropDownMultiPick inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)`

And the warning points to this code :

```
  10 |   const toggleDropdown = () => {
> 11 |     setIsOpen(!isOpen);
     |     ^
  12 |   };
```

#### my component

```
const DropDownMultiPick = ({ title, options, selectedOptions, handleOptionsChange }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [tempSelectedOptions, setTempSelectedOptions] = useState([...selectedOptions]);

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  ...
```

#### My test

```
const title = "Test Options";
const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"];
const selectedOptions = ["Option 1"];
const handleOptionsChange = jest.fn();
  it("should open and close the dropdown menu on toggle button click", async () => {
    render(
      <DropDownMultiPick
        title={title}
        options={options}
        selectedOptions={selectedOptions}
        handleOptionsChange={handleOptionsChange}
      />
    );

    const user = userEvent.setup();

    const toggleButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Option 1" });

    await user.click(toggleButton);
    // expect(await screen.findByRole("button", { name: /done/i })).toBeInTheDocument();

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /done/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

#### What I tried

I added an `act` in my component.  The warning is gone, but I don't think it is the best solution to add the `act` at this place!

```
const DropDownMultiPick = ({ title, options, selectedOptions, handleOptionsChange }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [tempSelectedOptions, setTempSelectedOptions] = useState([...selectedOptions]);

  const toggleDropdown = async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    });
  };
```

#### Question

What is the best solution to get rid of this warning?  I looked on this website, but it dit not help : https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning

## EDIT

The whole component :

```
// src/components/batchrec/dropdown-menu-multipick.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./dropdown-menu-multipick.styles.scss";

const DropDownMultiPick = ({ title, options, selectedOptions, handleOptionsChange }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [tempSelectedOptions, setTempSelectedOptions] = useState([...selectedOptions]);

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleItemClick = (option) => {
    if (tempSelectedOptions.includes(option)) {
      setTempSelectedOptions(tempSelectedOptions.filter((item) => item !== option));
    } else {
      setTempSelectedOptions([...tempSelectedOptions, option]);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handleDone = () => {
    handleOptionsChange(tempSelectedOptions);
    handleClose();
  };

  return (
    <div className="dropdown-multipick__container">
      <span className="label-title-style-5">
        <span className="dropdown-multipick__text label-title-style-1">{title}: </span>
        <button className="dropdown-multipick__toggle" onClick={toggleDropdown}>
          {selectedOptions.join(", ") || "Select..."}
        </button>
      </span>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className="dropdown-multipick__menu">
          {options.map((option, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={`dropdown-multipick__item ${
                tempSelectedOptions.includes(option) ? "dropdown-multipick__item--selected" : ""
              }`}
              onClick={() => handleItemClick(option)}
            >
              {option}
            </div>
          ))}
          <button className="dropdown-multipick__done" onClick={handleDone}>
            Done
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownMultiPick;
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more code on how `toggleDropdown` is called? Is there any asynchronous events?

Comment: `act` is supposed to be put in the test, not in your components.
You can try to wrap the `user.click` event into an `act`

Comment: @AngYC Added the whole component.  I don't see any async event in there!  I don't get it.

Comment: @aquinq Yes, this will silence the warning, but I'll get another warning from visual studio code.  This rule aims to avoid the usage of act to wrap Testing Library utils just to silence "not wrapped in act(...)" warnings.. https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-act.md

Comment: Hi @peterphonic, it seems like this can be caused by mismatch between your `@testing-library/react` version and `@testing-library/user-event`. Can you try upgrading both of them to latest version? (`@testing-library/react@14.0.0` and `@testing-library/user-event@14.4.3`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug on `react-testing-library` itself when used with React 18. The bug fix has already been merged in [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/pull/1137) and released in `@testing-library/react` version `14.0.0`.

You can update your `@testing-library/react` to the [latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react?activeTab=versions) and it should solve the issue.